# rails how to parse array of permutations to create records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, permutation

From

```
  a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I create array with

```
 a.permutation(5).to_a 
 => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],.......
```

How can I parse the array so I can create records assigning the index of array to the Model.attribute. Something like.....

```
for_each do
Model.create(n1: 1, n2: 2, n3: 3, n4: 4, n5: 5)
end
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) for this:

```
arrays = a.permutation(5).to_a

arrays.each do |array|
  attribs = array.map.with_index { |item, i| ["n#{i + 1}", item] }.to_h
  Model.create(attribs)
end
```

Comment: Its still unclear how to assign the index values to attribute_n1, n2, n3 etc. Can you please clarify or finish the example?

Comment: @Francisco -- The code also does that. The first line of `arrays.each` maps the items to a hash. The key will be `n` followed by the index of the item, and the value will be the item itself.